# Uniquely identify one computer

Tags: php, firefox

I work for a university, and i'm implementing a PHP web app that needs to have different behavior when it is visited from one certain computer.  The problem i am running into is that from the webserver, using *$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']* and *gethostbyaddr()*, i can only identify the router that a computer is going through, and not a specific computername.

Is there anyway i can set that one specific computer to identify itself to the server so the server knows when the webapp is being accessed from that machine?  The computer is running firefox in kiosk mode, so addons or greasemonkey scripts are allowed...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set a cookie.  This will be remembered by the client and transmitted to the server as part of every request.  More information here: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_cookies.asp

Comment: Unfortunately, if somebody have access to the computer he can stole cookie and set same cookie at other computer.

Comment: @Dmitriy Unfortunately, there's not likely to be any solution that can't be broken by direct physical access to the machine.

Answer (score 7):

[Change Firefox's user agent header][1] to something that uniquely identifies that machine, you can then extract this string in PHP from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

Answer (score 4):

You could set a cookie, or alternatively, you could modify the UserAgent header that your Firefox installation is using to something distinctive.

> To change the User Agent string, just
>   enter about:config as an address in
>   the address bar of FireFox, the
>   location where you normally enter a
>   URL (link). I recommend to preserve
>   the original value, which you can get
>   when you enter just about:  in the
>   address bar.
>
> Now press the right mouse button to
>   get the context menu and select
>   "String" from the menu entry "New".
>   Enter the preference name
>   "general.useragent.override", without
>   the quotes. Next, enter the new User
>   Agent value you want Mozilla Firefox
>   to use. I added my name and a link to
>   my web site to the original value. You
>   can also pick one from the list of
>   User Agent strings. Check the new
>   value by entering about: in the
>   address bar.

You can retrieve this User-Agent string from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in php.

Answer (score 3):

How about ssl and client certificates?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

- Set a durable cookie.  (Since FF is in kiosk mode, you should be safe from the users clearing it.)
- Have that kiosk use a different URL (perhaps with a query string parameter).

What I **wouldn't** do is work according to the machine's MAC address (which [Gibson](http://grc.com) tells us is possible) or similar; too fragile when hardware gets fixed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement an authentication system and place those users who need the special functionality into a special group?

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you got a very good answer but if you are looking for solution that uniquely identifies the COMPUTER rather than the BROWSER then look in to FLASH COOKIES a.k.a FLASH SHARED OBJECTS.

Theses are more powerful and can be used to store data up to 100KB and remains the same across all browsers that has flash, so it is better solution to uniquely identifying a user

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$something=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

To uniquely identify user check `$something` matches your own.(which is on your php code).
if yes then proceed access.

Answer (score -4):

Don't you have a SessionID ? 
Your sessionID should be unique enough to identify a computer.

Comment: Not if they close the browser.

Comment: Just agreeing with ceejayoz. Not relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: Interestingly enough you guys completely misunderstood the answer. Obviously the sessionID is in the cookie, and cookies are maintained even if you close the browser.