# How to uniquely identify a computer?

Tags: php

Is there any way to 'grab' some personalized ID, INFO, NAME, NUMBER, DATA, etc.?

Anything just to differentiate and recognize two or more PC on the same IP: something like the Computer name of the user besides `$_SESSION`?

None of these work:

```
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
php_uname('n');
php_uname();
```

Comment: This seems similar, in principle, to the question: [Uniquely identify one computer (tagged 'php')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331046/uniquely-identify-one-computer), but not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you won't be able to do this from only the HTTP request, but you do have at your disposal the following techniques:

1. Remote Address
2. Cookies/Session
3. User Agent
4. Client-side Web Technologies (e.g. Java or Flash or Silverlight object)

Basically, you can use the concepts of [Evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) to identifiy a client.  That being said, why not just use a login system?

Comment: I like this answer because it shows forward thinking rather than saying 'trust me, don't do this'.

Comment: https://app.bitsgap.com/trading, doing this well. but don't know what they are using.

Comment: @halfpastfour.am me too i want people who say let us look at possibilities not that cannot be done.

Answer (score 9):

No.

(At least not without the users' explicit cooperation.)

Comment: I thought about answering, but I just couldn't bring myself to do so. +1 for having the balls to 'just say no.' =)

Comment: @David @Oli :) I realized that, but I had hope... I'll try to create a jQuery cookie with some sort of generated ID ('time' or something) and pass it to a php string that in combination with the user IP something like: `$userId = md5(getenv(REMOTE_ADDR).''.$cookieTime);` and store this into a temp file on the server. :| Is that ok? :)

Comment: and what if i have user cooperation?

Answer (score 3):

There's plenty of information that can be used to create a browser 'fingerprint', but nothing that's guaranteed to be unique. You can find a list of the various data point [at the Panopticlick site](http://panopticlick.eff.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use OCS inventory! http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/en/