# Start session in a defined computer in PHP

Tags: php, session, unique, defined

I'm new in this forum but I use it every time when I have a question.

I need to start session in a defined computer using PHP, the method that I think to used is get a unique serial number from a computer (Windows, Mac, Linux or Android), but I can't find the way to get that unique SN of any device (preferable Motherboard SN or Bios) it can be using PHP or JS.

Getting that SN I can save it in a DB to compare it each time that someone Start session.

Do you have a better idea?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I uniquely identify computers visiting my web site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216542/how-do-i-uniquely-identify-computers-visiting-my-web-site)

Comment: Does this apply to the server side or the client side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216542/how-do-i-uniquely-identify-computers-visiting-my-web-site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331046/uniquely-identify-one-computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in comments above,

I don't believe it's actually possible to identify any computer, if it doesn't cooperate the right way.

If you want to distinguish computers from each other, you need some piece of information, some comparable difference. However, everything which comes from user can be modified by user, so you can't rely on it.

IP addresses can't be changed to any value randomly, if one wishes to receive response from server, but it's possible to use proxy servers. You can't use any headers or any sort of browser data either, as first more skilled user can change that within seconds- just think of netcat.